# Error when trying to add records to table with previously created records

Tags: winforms, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

This is my access form

[image]

When I search for a product the form fills with previous created data. The previously created data is created in another form which is very similar but instead of a find button it has a create button. The product ID is added to a separate table to the information in the sub-forum.

[image]

I get the error when I open the sub-form with previously created data. I get an error saying the changes you requested were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index.

[image]

What I want is to be able to search for a certain product and be able to add more operations to that product.

I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time and am unsure about how to solve the problem , any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your indexes, this usually happens when you forget to populate the parent ID into the child form before the insert happens.